# Python lib subprocess

Tags: python-2.7

Alguém sabe por que ele abre os 2 terminais com o mesmo comando " ls -la " ?

```
import subprocess

cmd = ["xterm"]

cmd.extend(['-e','bash','-c', 'ls -la; exec $SHELL'])

subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

cmd.extend(['-e','bash','-c','ping google.com; exec $SHELL'])

.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Answer (score 1):

**cmd** aponta para uma lista, que é um objeto mutável. Isso quer dizer que quando você estende **cmd** pela segunda vez você modifica o valor ainda do mesmo objeto, e é isso o que você tem:

```
>>> cmd.extend(['-e','bash','-c', 'ls -la; exec $SHELL'])
>>> cmd.extend(['-e','bash','-c','ping google.com; exec $SHELL'])
>>> cmd
['xterm', '-e', 'bash', '-c', 'ls -la; exec $SHELL', '-e', 'bash', '-c', 'ping google.com; exec $SHELL']
```

Desde que, nesse caso, só é possível executar um comando por vez e, sendo "ls -la" o primeiro em **cmd**, será ele executado nas duas chamadas de subprocess.Popen().
Talvez o que você queira seja isso:

```
import subprocess

cmd = ["xterm"]

cmd.extend(['-e','bash','-c', 'ls -la; exec $SHELL'])
subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
# novo comando, subscreve objeto
cmd = ["xterm"]

cmd.extend(['-e','bash','-c','ping google.com; exec $SHELL'])
subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Subscrevendo o objeto **cmd** conseguimos para cada comando uma instância do term.

- [Objects, values and types](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types)
- [Mutable objects](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-mutable)